# CFNetwork internal error (0xc01a:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CFNetwork_Sim/CFNetwork-808.2.16/Loading/URLConnectionLoader.cpp:304)

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, alamofire, sdwebimage

```
appName[8121:97068] 8121: CFNetwork internal error (0xc01a:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CFNetwork_Sim/CFNetwork-808.2.16/Loading/URLConnectionLoader.cpp:304)
```

I have a chat app, and I want to send an image to others.

I: IPhone ; others: simulator

I take a photo by camera, and press "use this photo",then I'll send an url to others and upload image to server.
Others receive url message immediately, and I use sdWebimage to show this image. 
But,when I receive the image, the image request print log error.
log say this image don't exist.
I dont know make this image download error,whether the image is uploading and the server don't have this image or not.
How can prevent this situation or have any function to set download again after 10 seconds of downloading error ?

this is my sd_image func:

```
 cell.photoImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: nil, options: .progressiveDownload, progress: nil
                        , completed: { (image, error, cacheType, url) in

 guard image != nil else{
       print("Image not exist!")
       cell.photoImageView.image = resizeImage(image:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "img_refresh"), newWidth: 125)
       return
 }

  print("image here!!!")

  DispatchQueue.global().async {
      let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch

                                if data != nil
                                {
                                    if let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                                    {
                                        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
                                            if let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.001)
                                            {
                                                do {
                                                    try jpegData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
                                                    print("image save local done!!!")
                                                } catch {
                                                    debug(object: error)
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            print("image already esist")

                                        }

                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            cell.photoImageView.image = resizeImage(image: image, newWidth: 175)

                                            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    })
```

uploading

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let uuid = NSUUID().uuidString
    let imageName:String = chatroomId + "_" + uuid + ".jpg"
    let documentsPath = NSHomeDirectory().appending("/Documents/\(chatroomId)/")
    let imagePath = documentsPath.appending(imageName)
    let imageUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath)
    print("imageUrl is here:\(imageUrl)")

    photoImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage


    if picker.sourceType == .camera {

        photoImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(photoImage!, nil, nil, nil)
    }

    let imageData:Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photoImage!, 0.001)!
    do {
        try imageData.write(to: imageUrl,options: .atomic)
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }

    //uploading
        let objectKey:String = "chatroom/" + imageName
        server.uploadObjectAsync(imageUrl, objectKey: objectKey)
        let message = server.url + imageName
        self.room.send(message: message)
        self.tableView.scrollToBottom()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Try to check whether image is getting uploaded on server or not. Ask your backend guy to verify that.

Answer (score 0):

try to add .allowInvalidSSLCertificates to your sd_setImage function :

```swift
cell.photoImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: nil, options: .allowInvalidSSLCertificates, progress: nil
                        , completed: { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
```